# barcode scanner is not working on some devices using ionic framework android

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic capacitor project for my android and ios app using typescript.

I am using the following for scanner for my application:

```
"@capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning": "^5.0.0",
```

The barcode scanner is working fine on most devices. But I am using my device(Redmi 11i 5g, OnePlus Nord), When I click the scan button, white screen is opening and immediately closed. When I am checking debugger, it shows error like below:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Failed to scan code.
Error: Failed to scan code.
    at returnResult (VM3:912:32)
    at win.androidBridge.onmessage (VM3:887:21)
    at Y (polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1:16047)
    at polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1:15137
    at polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1:15243
    at f (main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1:1196775)
    at q (main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1:1196994)
    at v.invoke (polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1:6632)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1:910645)
    at v.invoke (polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1:6572)
    at h.run (polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1:1998)
    at polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1:16842
handleError @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
next @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
__tryOrUnsub @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
next @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
_next @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
next @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
next @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
emit @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
run @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
runOutsideAngular @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
onHandleError @ main.254b30b8ea673a5c.js:1
handleError @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
runGuarded @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
s.microtaskDrainDone @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
T @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
Promise.then (async)
X @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
C @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
ee @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
Y @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.441dd4ca9dc0674f.js:1
returnResult @ VM3:929
win.androidBridge.onmessage @ VM3:887
```

This is happening on 'Release Mode' also on my mobile. My ionic version is: Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 7.1.1 (C:\Users\manthiram.c\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli) Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 7.5.3 @angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.2.8 @angular-devkit/schematics : 16.2.8 @angular/cli : 16.2.8 @ionic/angular-toolkit : 9.0.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI : 5.6.0 @capacitor/android : 5.6.0 @capacitor/core : 5.6.0 @capacitor/ios : not installed

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed globally native-run : 2.0.0

System:

NodeJS : v16.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe) npm : 8.12.2 OS : Windows 10

I want to work scanner on all devices.